# Magento 2 Product Title and Description Changes Not Showing In Frontend

Tags: magento2

When I update a product Title and Description in Magento 2 Admin, it saves properly, but the changes don't show in the frontend even after flushing caches. Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: can u please give me screens shot where you have updating product title?

Comment: Which mode your magento having ?

Comment: I updated the product title and description on the product editing page in Magento 2.

Comment: @Pawan the store is in production mode. The changes are taking place or showing in the admin, but are not showing on the frontend.

Comment: Try run this command in shell on magento 2 root directory php bin/magento i:rei

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command and check.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Please, run the below command and check.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-store feature.in case the "Use Default Value" is unchecked for name, description and short-description. Which means that any change to the default won't be shown in a storeview.so ,after change 'Use Default Value' checked,

Make sure next to the change field, the following checkbox was checked:

[ ] Use Default Value

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches/solution for your issue

1. ReIndexing the product data.
2. Enable Flat Catalog